# Navigate between page tabs when the browser's Back and Forward buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a simple jQuery tab working fine. The code for this feature is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabHead = $('ul li');
    var tabContent = $('.content');

    tabContent.not(':first').hide().end();
    tabHead.on('click',function() { 
        tabContent.hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
    });
});
```

And the HTML markup for the tabs is:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#content1">Head 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#content2">Head 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content"> Some Content/........</div>
<div class="content"> Some Content/........</div>
```

However, when I click the "Back" and "Forward" buttons of the browser, only the url changes e.g.

```
http://some-path/demo-tabs/#tab2
```

The content of the tab does not show up. How can I make the tab's content also show up on clicking the "Back" or "Forward" buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for the `"hashchange"` event on the window object, and trigger a click on the relevant anchor link when that's fired.

You can target the correct link using the jQuery [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). That looks something like this: `a[href='#tab1']`. You can get the link's href from the URL via the `window.location.hash` property.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
    $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").click();
});
```

Take a look at this [list of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=hash) that support the `hashchange` event.

Comment: hey nbrooks...the code you have suggested does the work. But now there seems to be a page reload or page jump when I click on the tab. I cannot give the e.preventDefault() too. Could you suggest an way out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` instead of `href`

```
 <ul>    
        <li><a id="#content1">Head 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="#content2">Head 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content"> Some Content/........</div>
    <div class="content"> Some Content3........</div>
```

This will prevent change in URL
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4eu8a34/3/)

Comment: i did not want to prevent the url from changing.....i wanted it to change along with the tab content on clicking the prev and next buttons of the browser